# Query count at the column with delimiter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column with data like below.

```
A1
A2
A3
A1/B1
A1/B2
A1/B1/C1
```

Usually I copy then to excel and use the text to column function then count. 
Can I use query command to count them directly at server? 
Example count 
How do I count total number 
Which does not has / is 3
which has one / is 2
which has two / is 1

**updated for SQL query**

```
select ( len(colA) - len(replace(colA, '/', '')) ) as num_slashes 
from DBO.table1
```

**got the result**

**how to count 0 has 3 counts, 1 has 2 counts, 2 has 1 count?**

```
0
0
0
1
1
2
```

Comment: Don't store data like that (/ separated items). It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: What kind of problem? It was designed by architect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Postgres has a function like `regexp_count()`.  One method is the difference of the lengths of two strings.  You can use:

```
select ( length(col) - length(replace(col, '/', '')) ) as num_slashes,
       count(*)
from t
group by num_slashes
order by num_slashes;
```

Perhaps a more Postgres-y way of doing this converts the value to an array and then takes the length:

```
select array_length(string_to_array(col, '/'), 1) - 1
```

Comment: Or just split with `string_to_array`. No need to involve regex.

Comment: the length and string to array function is not supported in mssql. any alternate function can be used?

Comment: @user12158726 . . . The equivalent function is `len()`.

Comment: len() can be used but still 'num_slashes' returned Invalid column name 'num_slashes'.

Comment: select ( len(itemid) - len(replace(itemid, '/', '')) ) as num_slashes from item.items group by num_slashes

Comment: updated main post, got result but unsure how to count them

Comment: @user12158726 . . . In MS SQL, you have to repeat the expression in the `GROUP BY`.  You can't `GROUP BY` a column alias.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how do i make both statements works? i mean parse the first statement result to continue for 2nd statement to group it?

Comment: @user12158726 . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question specifically about MS SQL.